# What is happening here in this code from codefights?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read code, but I don't really get this over here. The comments are how I read this code:

```
def firstDuplicate(a)
   counts = []                       #make an empty array named counts
   a.each do |value|                 #go through a
     return value if counts[value]   #a[0]: return 2 if counts[2]???
     counts[value] = true            #counts[2] = true???? wtf???
   end
   -1                                #return -1 if none of the above
 end
```

This question is from codefights.com:

> Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to
>   `a.length`, find the first duplicate number for which the second
>   occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more
>   than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second
>   occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other
>   number does. If there are no such elements, `return -1`.
>
> Example
>
> For `a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`, the output should be `firstDuplicate(a) = 3`.
>
> There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3
>   has a smaller index than than second occurrence of 2 does, so the
>   answer is 3.
>
> For `a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]`, the output should be `firstDuplicate(a) = -1` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is just using the array `counts` to track whether a value was previously seen. In this case, the code could use a `Hash` just as easily as an `Array`.

Consider your example array, `[2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`.

Right before the array is iterated, `counts` looks like `[]` - it is empty.

As we start iterating the example array, the first value we see is `2`. The first line of code in the loop checks to see if `counts[value]` is truthy, but `counts` is still empty so `counts[2]` returns `nil`, which is not truthy. So we move down to the next line and set `counts[2]` to `true`. `counts` now looks like: `[nil, nil, true]`. (arrays are zero-indexed, meaning the first element is at index 0, the second is at index 1, third at index 2, etc).

Now, we move to the top of the loop again and process the second value in the array, `3`. `counts[3]` is also nil (which is falsey), so we can't return yet. Thus, we set `counts[3]` to `true` and go back to the top of the loop to process the next element in the array. Now `counts` looks like: `[nil, nil, true, true]`.

Now we are at the third element in the array, which is another `3`.

This time around, we check `counts[3]` to see if it is truthy. `counts` still looks like `[nil, nil, true, true]`, so `counts[3]` is `true`. Since `counts[3]` is true, we return `3`.

If no duplicate values were found in the array, then we would have finished going through the loop and end up at the line of code with `-1`. Ruby methods return the value that the last line of code in the method evaluates to, which is `-1` in this case. Therefore if no duplicates are found, we get a `-1` as the result.